# deployjava.getJREs is not working for windows 7 64 bit jre

Tags: java, javascript, windows-7, internet-explorer-9, deployjava

I am trying to get jre version in windows7, I have installed the 64 bit jre for the same,
but when I use deployjava.js getJres method it gives me blank list of jre installed, it is working fine for me for 32 bit windows.

please help me out.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I think I had the same problem and found:

JRE 64bits will not work with IE 32 bits. 
And vice versa:
JRE 32bits will not work with IE 64 bits.

Install JRE 32 bits if you want to use IE in 32 bits mode (which is default).